# Change spaces to underscores in filename - Linux

Tags: linux, command-line

I need to convert any and all files with a space or spaces in the names to underscores from a given path.

Right now I have `for file in *; do mv "$file" ${file// /_}; done`

How would I go about changing that to a specific directory and run it?

This command will also only show the new files ( not dir's, hidden files etc.)

`ls -1ap ${newDir} | grep -v /`

Comment: Hm, why don't you put the path before wildcard parameter?`for file in /path/to/your/directory/*; do mv "$file" ${file// /_}; done`

Comment: Can you just `cd` to the dir you want to do this in?

Comment: Or, instead of `cd`, look at `pushd` and `popd`